# ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: This isn't a buyer account

Tags: unit-test, b2b-commerce

When i am writing test class for Commerce Cloud. Then Account is necessary is buyer account. How i can enable Acount.IsBuyer field to true in test class. In UI i can enable as buyer account by click on button "Enable Buyer Account".

As isBuyer is not writable in Apex Code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try below code and see if it works

```
BuyerAccount buyerAccount = new BuyerAccount();
buyerAccount.BuyerId = account.Id;
buyerAccount.Name = 'Test Buyer Account (BA-AJ)';
buyerAccount.IsActive = true;
insert buyerAccount;
```

Comment: Thank you @swetha.